# how to take an action when user enters a screen or navigates away from it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

This is my app container:

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    createUser: CreateUser,
    showUsers: ShowUsers,
    editUser: EditUser
});
```

in `createUser` I make new users and save them in my database, and in `showUsers` on `componentDidMount` lifecycle I get the data from my database and list them. but since screens don't unmount when we navigate away from them, the `componentDidMount` lifecycle is just called the first time, so each time I get previews data, and I have to reload my app to see the result.
how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React navigation has a lifecycle api, to do exactly what you describe:

For more information check the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html

Part of that API is a **withNavigationFocus** HOC, and this provides an isFocused prop which indicates if a screen is visible.

Example:

```js
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class SomeScreen extends React.Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.isFocused && !prevProps.isFocused) {
      // Screen has now come into focus
    }
  }

}

export default withNavigationFocus(SomeScreen)
```